# Angular subscription is not working as I expect

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

So I have a shop page with a child component called FilterBarComponent and onInit I want it to emit all the category as by default I want all the products in the shop to be rendered, but on my homePageComponent I have a button that allows a user to navigate to the shopPage and view a specific category for e.g a button that says "view shirts". My problem is that the default categories array occurs after the subscriber function finishes and also in the subscriber the event emitter does not fire.
Here is another question of mine that relates to this problem.
[Angular EventEmitter is not emitting in subscriber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61695952/angular-eventemitter-is-not-emitting-in-subscriber)

FilterBarComponent

```
  categories = [];

  @Output() filteredCategory = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() maxiumPriceEmitter = new EventEmitter<any>();
  categorySub: Subscription;
  formatLabel(value: number) {
    return 'R' + value;
  }

  constructor(private shopService: ShopService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initCategories();
    this.filterCategories();
    this.updateCategories();
  }

filterCategories() {
    this.shopService.filterCategories.subscribe(
        (fCategory: string) => {
        this.categories.map(category => {
            category.checked = category.name === fCategory;
          });
        this.updateCategories();
        });
  }
  initCategories() {
    this.categories = [
      { name: 'dress', checked: true, displayName: 'Dresses' },
      { name: 'top', checked: true, displayName: 'Shirts' },
      { name: 'skirt', checked: true, displayName: 'Skirts/Pants' },
      { name: 'purse', checked: true, displayName: 'Purse' },
      { name: 'bag', checked: true, displayName: 'Bags' },
    ];

  }

  updateCategories() {
    const categories = this.categories
      .filter((category) => {
        return category.checked;
      });
    console.log(categories);
    this.filteredCategory.emit(categories);
  }
```

in the console at first I get the correct result
but then categories array resets

```
[{}]
{name: "top", checked: true, displayName: "Shirts"}

[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
{name: "dress", checked: true, displayName: "Dresses"}
1: {name: "top", checked: true, displayName: "Shirts"}
2: {name: "skirt", checked: true, displayName: "Skirts/Pants"}
3: {name: "purse", checked: true, displayName: "Purse"}
4: {name: "bag", checked: true, displayName: "Bags"}
length: 5
```

the Observable in ShopService

```
filterCategories = new BehaviorSubject("category");
```

Comment: Can you show the template code?

Comment: @Paul Have a look at the updated code now

Comment: Could you elaborate on `My problem is that when the subscription to filter for a specific category is fired the result happens before the default settings are emitted.`.  There's a couple ways to interpret that.  Could you provide a list of steps which recreates the issue.  Because I see one potential cause, but I want to ensure I understand the problem first.

Comment: @Paul I edited the Question at the top

Comment: yeah your title does say something totally reverse

Comment: Yeh Sorry I had a hard time making a proper title, I changed it now, still dont know what to title the question

Comment: Do you really need to call `this.updateCategories();` twice?  It's called directly in `filterCategories`, and `ngOnInit`.

Comment: I call it in ngOnInit as I want it to emit all the categories to the shopComponent so that it can render all the products

Comment: Is your expectation that the event emitter is invoked twice on `ngOnInit`?  Once directly in `ngOnInit` and once indirectly by `filterCategories` which is called by `ngOnInit`?  So, can you provide the source of `ShopService`?

Comment: @Paul I have added the observable used in the shopService

Comment: What's invoking  `filterCategories.next`?

Comment: a `BehaviorSubject` is different from an `EventEmitter`.  You used an event emitter to emit the data which emit data to parent component. If you want your BehaviorSubject subscribers get the data, you must use it's to `next(categories)`

Answer (score 0):

I owe this answer to @Józef Podlecki for another question that he answered of mine.

I need to use a BehaviorSubject instead of a regular subject in the ShopService

```
filterCategories = new BehaviorSubject("all");
```

Filter Bar Component

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initCategories();
    this.filterCategories();
  }

  filterCategories() {
    this.shopService.filterCategories.subscribe((fCategory: string) => {
      if (fCategory === 'all') {
        this.updateCategories();
      } else {
        this.categories.map((category) => {
          category.checked = category.name === fCategory;
        });
        this.updateCategories();
      }
    });
  }
```